# HDMI not detected after update in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 and for some reason when I restarted my computer my hdmi stopped being recognized. What's going on and how do I fix this?

Here's my output with `lspci -v -s 00:02.0`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. Device 2111
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
Kernel driver in use: i915
```

and `xrandr` output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 32767 x 32767
VGA1 connected primary 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 430mm x 270mm
    1680x1050      60.0*+
    1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
    1152x864       75.0  
    1024x768       75.1     60.0  
    800x600        75.0     60.3  
    640x480        75.0     60.0  
    720x400        70.1  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

HDMI is not disconnected and should be read. Going into Displays I do not see the second screen. I have seen multiple issue tracking on this but have not managed to solve it yet.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/345622/hdmi-stopped-working-ubuntu-13-04

It seems like a video card problem but I would have suspected that I would have noticed this before not now. Maybe this has to do with the ubuntu update that I made before the restart???

I'm adding the specs of my motherboard below. I am using the integrated graphics card.

```
description: Desktop Computer
    product: MS-7758 (To be filled by O.E.M.)
    vendor: MSI
    version: 1.0
    serial: To be filled by O.E.M.
    width: 32 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 smp-1.4 smp
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=desktop cpus=4 family=To be filled by O.E.M. sku=To be filled by O.E.M. uuid=00000000-0000-0000-0000-D43D7E921319
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: Z77A-G43 (MS-7758)
       vendor: MSI
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.0
       serial: To be filled by O.E.M.
       slot: To be filled by O.E.M.
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: V2.7
          date: 10/24/2012
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 8128KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
```

Comment: If you can even tell me how to reset my driver to an older version before the update that might work as a temporary fix.